# Node.js returning partially duplicate row from MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm new to Node.js and "asynchronous land" and have met some strange problems.

### Things I intended to do:

Node.js query from MySQL

### What was the problem:

the row query from Node.js got partially duplicate columns.

e.g. Here's the result by looking up the MySQL directly, please notice the `userId`:

`user1` is ending with `36` and `user2` is ending with `37`

[image]

and here's the output from Node.js

[image]

I've got `user1` and `user2` with same `userId`, although other columns are correct.

### Code:

I created the table `userInfo` using the following:

```sql
create table userInfo(userId bigint, userName text, userEmail text, userNetwork text, userAvatar blob);
```

and populate it using:

```sql
insert into userInfo values(uuid_short(), 'user1', 'user@test.com', 'facebook', null);
insert into userInfo values(uuid_short(), 'user2', 'user2@test.com', 'facebook', null);
```

The Node.js code I'm using:

```js
var http = require("http"), 
// And url module, which is very helpful in parsing request parameters. 
    url = require("url"),
    // add sql module
    mysql = require("mysql");

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: "root",
    password: "xxxxxx",
    database: "db"
})
// show message at console
console.log('Node.js server is running.'); 
// Create the server. 
http.createServer(function (request, response) { 
    request.resume();
    // Attach listener on end event. 
    request.on("end", function () {
        // Parse the request for arguments and store them in _get variable. 
        // This function parses the url from request and returns object representation. 
        var _get = url.parse(request.url, true).query; 
        // query the database
        connection.connect();
        var getInfo = _get['getInfo'];
        var qString = new Buffer(getInfo, 'base64').toString('utf8');
            console.log(qString);
        connection.query(qString, function (error, rows, fields) {
                if (error) {
                    throw error;
                }
        if (rows.length > 0) {
                // send the data as json
                console.log(JSON.stringify(rows));
                response.end(JSON.stringify(rows));
            } else {
                // send code 200 json as there are no rows
                response.end(JSON.stringify({code:200}));
            }
        });
    });
}).listen(8080);
```

This problem persists even I've replaced this

`connection.query(qString, function (error, rows, fields)`

into

`connection.query('SELECT * FROM userId', function (error, rows, fields)`

Could you tell me where I'm heading wrong?

I guess the problem is I'm not coping well with asynchronous?

### UPDATE

I tried the same SQL and code on another machine(windows machine) and the result are the same, with every other columns correct but the `userId`:

Query from MySQL:

[image]

Query using Node.js:

[image]

After this test, I thought about the problem may come from the `Big Int` that JSON cannot handle correctly. Thus I switched all my output using [json-bigint](https://www.npmjs.org/package/json-bigint), however, the problem still not get resolved:

[image]

Comment: This has nothing to do with asynchronism … Using integers for the user ids _is_ the root of your problem – JavaScript can’t handle integer values that large, so they are treated as floats instead, and with that you get a problem with the inherent accuracy problems of floats … Store them as text.

Comment: @CBroe thx for the help. But why the example in https://www.npmjs.org/package/json-bigint seemed handle the big int correctly? The author just using `var` to store the big int, so why there aren't any problems?

Comment: Most likely the problem occurs before you’re making JSON out of the data already, between your SQL server and your node.js app – if your database passes these values to your JavaScript _as integers_, then that it where the loss of precision occurs already … so whatever you use on the data _after_ that will not make a difference any more.

Comment: @CBroe thx man, I got it. Is there any way to "safely" retrieve the big ints from database without changing in the database side?

Comment: You would have to make absolutely sure that they are _treated_ as strings, from the very start where they enter your app all the way through the whole processing chain … so your best way to go is to put them into a text column the database in the first place. There is absolutely no value in having them in there as integers in the first place. (Don’t even begin to argue with storage space requirements, that would be nonsense.) This is common best practice, even Facebook themselves say that you should not store their IDs as integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `bigNumberStrings` driver [connection option](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#connection-options) to true, that way big numbers are serialised in result as a string:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: "root",
    password: "xxxxxx",
    database: "db",
    supportBigNumbers: true,
    bigNumberStrings: true       
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "",
  password: "",
  database: ""
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
  var sql = "INSERT INTO studentdetails(fname,lname,age,dob,streetname,city,state,pincode) VALUES ('aaa','bbb',22,'1994-05-13','PC','MTM','qqqq',1242352)";
  **con.query(sql, function (err,rows,result) {
    if (err) throw err;


          if (rows.fname === sql.fname) {
             console.log('Already exist');

               }
               else {
                 console.log("1 record inserted");
               }** 
                con.end();
   });

  });




// is this correct to ignore the duplicate values??
suggest me an answer please
```

Answer (score 0):

Bigint-s will always be a pain in Javascript. You can try to hack your way around it, but why bother?

Two possible solutions:

1) Use smaller integers that don’t cross the threshold where their encoding in Javascript breaks, or

2) Use some other data type, such as string.

Comment: thx man, I got it. Is there any way to "safely" retrieve these big ints from database without changing in the database side?

Answer (score 0):

The magnitude of the integers is the problem, as others have pointed out.  Here are some additional bits to think about:

- Some brief googling suggests that they're working on standardizing some introspection for this in ES6.
- To see the maximum integer you can use in Chrome, open the console and output the value for `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` -- you'll see it's less than the value of your userIds.  The specific value is due to the limits of Javascript's internal floating-point representation -- beyond a certain size, integers become impossible to precisely express.
- Here's [a blog post](http://www.2ality.com/2013/10/safe-integers.html) that gets into the details.

Comment: thx for the details, its well-worth reading. I wonder is there any solutions on this other than changing the data type in the database?